# seekg() Gives Weird Results

Tags: visual-c++

The following block of codes, which are extracted from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/, do not work as expected in my version of Visual Studio.

```
// read a file into memory  
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream

int main () {
  std::ifstream is ("test.txt", std::ifstream::binary);
  if (is) {
    // get length of file:
    is.seekg (0, is.end);
    int length = is.tellg();
    is.seekg (0, is.beg);

    // allocate memory:
    char * buffer = new char [length];

    // read data as a block:
    is.read (buffer,length);

    is.close();

    // print content:
    std::cout.write (buffer,length);

    delete[] buffer;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

For example, when test.txt has the contents "hello\n", `length` is given a value of `2`. Why did this happen?

Comment: Whatever file you *actually* opened does not contain "hello\n".  It never does anyway, not on Windows.  It probably just contains "\r\n". Standard bug, always use the full path name of the file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I gave the full path name, but `length` was still `2`. When I read character by character from the file using `get()` up to `length`, I got `h` and `e`. So what happened?

Comment: Your version of Visual Studio isn't the same as mine.  Or anybody else's I suspect.  But we don't know what it is so it is just guessing.